# Superhero movie that takes place at a motel

Tags: story-identification, movie

A few years ago I watched a movie on Netflix about a superhero wearing a blue suit who checks into a motel and encounters two other heroes, a male and a female, and possibly fight each other. I can't find it anywhere and I don't remember the name of the film.

Comment: How many years ago? What else do you remember about this film?

Comment: There is an apparently very bad superhero movie I don't recognize where they lose their powers and are forced to fight by a supervillian called [_All Superheroes Must Die_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vs_(film)) or _Vs_.

Comment: @eshier - It's not great, but for the budget that film is pretty decent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "[Alter Egos](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1907614/)", a low-budget indie superhero movie released in 2012.

The opening scenes are set in a motel and a small diner.

Answer (score 3):

The description has similarities to *[The Tick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tick_(2001_TV_series))*, a live-action TV series from 2001.  The first episode opens with the blue-costumed title character guarding a bus station.  The Tick has a male sidekick and two hero friends (male and female).

[image: DVD cover image]

(Image source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242949/))

The series [was available on Netflix](http://usa.newonnetflix.info/info/70202897/s).